# A proper way to learn Angular 2 Observables

Tags: angular, angular2-services

To be honest, it's the first time when I am actually lost and don't know where to look for the proper tutorial on a subject.

I'm trying to understand Angular 2 Observables and Services. However all sources that I found only confuses me more, once they go past the simplest get request.

This is what I already tried:

1. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html (Angular 2
   Off. Hero app tutorial, HTTP part) - The best so far, but once it gets to Observables, they start throwing tons of .methods of Observable, without good explaining ,why and what each one of them does and how I can use them. I CAN re-type what they wrote and it WILL work, but it doesn't help me to understand what's going on.

   2. https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables - stopped at the point they implement an Event Emitter ,without explaining why and what. Too much unrelated information that only confuses me, as a beginner.

3.Ng-Book2 HTTP section - Was very good in a simple Get example, but then instantly jumps into creating an Observable for YouTube API. Just to clarify, this is the function they give me, without ANY explanaition:

```
    Observable.fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'keyup') 
    .map((e: any) => e.target.value) // extract the value of the input .filter((text: string) => text.length > 1) // filter out if empty .debounceTime(250) // only once every 250ms 
    .do(() => this.loading.next(true)) // enable loading 
    // search, discarding old events if new input comes in 
    .map((query: string) => this.youtube.search(query)) 
    .switch()
 .subscribe(  
(results: SearchResult[]) => { // on sucesss 
this.loading.next(false); 
this.results.next(results); 
}, 
(err: any) => { // on error 
console.log(err); 
this.loading.next(false); 
}, 
() => { // on completion 
this.loading.next(false); 
} 
 );
```

Sorry for the horrible formatting, it was hard to copy from the pdf book I bought on their website. Now I get that all those .map functions are YouTube API specific and used to get to the desired data and put it in corresponding class properties, but it doesn't help me learn Observables at all.

4.YouTube video tutorials I found - all of them use pre-release version of Angular 2.

So please, point me in the right direction. Is subscribe() the only real method I will use, working with Observables? Is EventEmitter necessary for the small application to showcase what Observables are? I will appreciate it if anyone has a good step by step tutorial that explains why and how.

I'm sorry if I ask the wrong question, I have nowhere else to go for an advice:)

Comment: Search for RxJs Observable, not angular (do not even include the word angular). Observable is from the RxJs library that Angular makes use of as do many other libraries / platforms.

Comment: Have fun with them, it's pretty long and cumbersome, but totally worth it in the end ! You could start from the Observable / Subscriber design pattern as well. There are a lot of books on this subject as well.

Comment: I'll try RxJs Observable. As for Angular 2, is there any good, consistent book/tutorial I can follow other than the official one? Like my personal favorite is http://javascriptissexy.com/how-to-learn-javascript-properly/ I followed it few years ago and it was the best thing for me to switch to JS. Is there anything like it for Angular 2 or its too young?